# Sharepoint 2016 :two types of authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sharepoint, active-directory

t is possible to configure two types of authentication sharepoint ? For users in LAN via Active direvtory and for external users (from internet) via sql server database ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You need to enable windows authentication and enable FBA for the web application. When you login, you could select which type to logon to the site.

[image]
[image]

Besides, you could refer to this article to configure fba:
https://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2016-sharepoint-2019-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/